# C++: which constructors are called in vector<int> vn{MyAllocator<int>(a)}?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, constructor-overloading

I have a trivial allocator:

```
// alloc.h
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Mallocator {
  typedef T value_type;
  Mallocator() {
        std::cout << "default ctor is called" << std::endl;
  }
  template <class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor is called" << std::endl;
  }
  T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
    std::cout << "Mallocator::allocate(size_t n) is called, n = " << n << " ";
    if(n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T)) throw std::bad_alloc();
    if(T *p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n*sizeof(T)))) {
        std::cout << "return p = " << std::hex << (uintptr_t)p << std::dec << std::endl;
        return p;
    }
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) { 
      std::cout << "Mallocator::deallocate(T *p, size_t n) is called, p = " << std::hex << (uintptr_t)p << std::dec << " n = " << n << std::endl;
      std::free(p);
  }
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return false; }
```

And this is the client code (only one of `A`, `B`, `C` is used):

```
#include "alloc.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mallocator<int> a;
    cout << "---instantiate---" << endl;
    // vector<int, Mallocator<int>> v(a);                  // A
    vector<int, Mallocator<int>> v{Mallocator<int>(a)};    // B
    // vector<int, Mallocator<int>> v(Mallocator<int>(a)); // C
    cout << "---push_back(1)---" << endl;
    v.push_back(1);
    cout << "---push_back(2)---" << endl;
    v.push_back(2);
    cout << "---push_back(3)---" << endl;
    v.push_back(3);
    cout << "---push_back(4)---" << endl;
    v.push_back(4);
    cout << "---push_back(5)---" << endl;
    v.push_back(5);
    cout << "---exiting---" << endl;
}
```

The output, no matter `A` or `B` is used, is always this:

```
default ctor is called
---instantiate---
---push_back(1)---
// omitted for brevity..
```

**My question**:

(1) if `A` is present, the allocator is just constructed once, that's understandable. But when `B` is present instead of `A`, apparently the copy constructor of `Mallocator` is called in `B`, but the output doesn't reflect this. Why?

(2) If `B` is present, which constructor of `std::vector` is called? In this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the only constructor that takes an initializer list doesn't look like this. And if I use `C` instead of `B`, it won't compile, and the error message of clang++ is not helping..

Eidt: I know this allocator is trivial but it is not the point of this question..

The code of "alloc.h" is adapted from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), at the end of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your "copy constructor" isn't one. A real copy constructor isn't a template. Every class gets a copy constructor implicitly declared if it doesn't declare one itself. `Mallocator<int>` doesn't declare a real copy constructor, so one gets implicitly declared and defined for you. Since your class is empty, that copy constructor does nothing and prints nothing (and, thanks to the overload resolution rules, is selected to copy the allocator over your constructor template).

2) List-initialization can call non-initializer-list constructors if no initializer-list constructor is viable. `B` ends up calling the same constructor as `A`. Your `C` is a case of the [most-vexing-parse](/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse).

Comment: yeah, that's right,  though with  fix to that code (removing template from U), it still will not call copy constructor's side effect. Or,  better to say, _maybe_ will not call.

Comment: @Swift You'll see at least one copy from the vector's parameter to the allocator it stores. That's not elidable.

Comment: that's unquestioned. Actually, I see two, which is curious(8) isn't  that the proper constructor that can be called in this case.

Comment: @Swift (That's because I will get notified anyway and there's no ambiguity about who you can be replying to.) The other is from the `Mallocator<int>(a)` part.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that.. it was a long day.

Comment: If I really want to have a user-defined copy constructor, how should I write it? I don't require the copied-from object's template argument be the same as the copied-to one - that's the reason why the "constructor" is a template method.

Comment: (Follow-up) And, based on your answer about constructors being non-templated, is it correct to say the source of the code (the link given at the end my question) does not achieve what it intends?

Comment: @user8385554 A copy constructor is `Mallocator(const Mallocator&) = default;`. The standard requires both the converting constructor template and the ordinary copy constructor. The cppreference example leaves out the explicit copy constructor declaration because the implicitly declared one does it job just fine.

Comment: @T.C. thanks for your friendly and informative comment, which is more useful than the other guy's condescending words. In fact, I found this allocator defines both copy constructor and converting constructor template, just like what you said: [stack_allocator](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/base/stack_container.h)